# Transform data structure in an array

Tags: jquery, json

I have a json format data like below:

```
"answers": [
  {
    "1": "Reputation",
    "3": "Nothing specific"
  }
]
```

What can I do if I want them to be like this?

```
"answers": [
  {
    "optId":"1",
    "optText":"Reputation"
  },
  {
    "optId":"3",
    "optText":"Nothing specific"
  }
]
```

Thanks.

Comment: Use `map()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: By using Object.keys(), you can get the attribute name (the left side) programmatically. Then it's just a matter of how you are pushing it into a new json array. Good luck.

Comment: What generates this format? It would be better to change it at source (if possible) than anything else

Comment: @A.Wolff It's a question with multiple checkbox, I ues `.each()` to get those answers which are checked. Originally, I just push the `id` and `text_of_answer` into two separate arrays and I serialize them into one array, so that's why I got this format.

Comment: You'd then have better to provide this relevant code in question itself. Although using @Shubham answer below should be enough because it should be fast enough if you don't have thousand of checkboxes

Answer (score 3):

```
let outputArr =[];

answers.forEach(ob=>{

 Object.keys(ob).forEach(key=>{
   outputArr.push({
    "optId":key,
    "optText":ob[key]
   })
 })

})
```